# SharePoint 2013 High-Trust App - Site Collection Provisioning

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, site-collection, provisioning

Hi I am trying to get an app done to provision a Site Collection.

The vision is to allow the user to enter important details and then click a button and have the Site Collection created automatically.

I have had a look at the following (very excellent) posts:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/04/04/self-service-site-provisioning-using-apps-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/08/23/site-provisioning-techniques-and-remote-provisioning-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

but these mention that Site provisioning via the App model can only be done for Office 365.

So, I tried to modify the code of the app in [Link 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/04/04/self-service-site-provisioning-using-apps-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx), to be used within a High trust provider hosted app.

Code:

```
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

        using(var clientContext = spContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
            webUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}", BasePath, Url);
            var properties = new SiteCreationProperties()
            {
                Url = webUrl,
                Owner = sAdministrator,
                Title = sTitle,
                Template = sSiteTemplate,
                StorageMaximumLevel = iStorageMaximum,
                UserCodeMaximumLevel = dUserCodeMaximum
            };
            SpoOperation op = tenant.CreateSite(properties);
            clientContext.Load(tenant);
            clientContext.Load(op, i => i.IsComplete);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //check if site creation operation is complete
            while (!op.IsComplete)
            {
                //wait 30seconds and try again
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                op.RefreshLoad();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
```

When executing the lines:

`SpoOperation op = tenant.CreateSite(properties);
                clientContext.Load(tenant);
                clientContext.Load(op, i => i.IsComplete);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();`

, the following error is thrown:

`Cannot find stub for type with id "{268004ae-ef6b-4e9b-8425-127220d84719}". The specified server may not support APIs used in this operation.`

Any ideas what this might be caused by?

I think this is either a problem in my environmental setup, or that site collection creation can only be done for an Office 365 site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up until [April 2014 Cumulative Update for the SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/05/08/april-2014-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-finally-been-released.aspx) release only Office 365 and SP Online supported the provisioning of site collections remotely using CSOM extensions (part of [the Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online package](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362.aspx)). [This set of functionalities was not available for on-premises (or Office365-Dedicated)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/01/02/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-in-on-premises.aspx).

With [April 2014 Cumulative Update for the SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/05/08/april-2014-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-finally-been-released.aspx) the capability of remote provisioning of site collections was introduced to *on-premises farm*.

### Requirements

> There are some pre-requirements to enable site collection provisioning
>   with CSOM in on-premises farm. Reasoning for these steps is that we’ve
>   tried to ensure minimum difference between on-premises and Office365
>   development patterns and there was no point introducing new CSOM API
>   which are specifically for the on-premises after the introduction of
>   site collection creation capability to the Offic365. Here’s the
>   required steps one by one. Notice that the PowerShell scripts are also
>   included in the [downloadable sample code](http://1drv.ms/1pVrRA3).
>
> 1. Install April 2014 Cumulative Update for the SharePoint 2013 to your
>      SharePoint 2013 farm Check [Stefan Goßner’s blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/05/08/april-2014-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-finally-been-released.aspx) for detailed
>      links and additional insights
> 2. Enable remote site collection creation using just CSOM by running
>      specific PowerShell script available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom.aspx)
> 3. Download the [Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) and install
>      that to your remote development environment where you write your
>      CSOM code This contains 15 version of the objects which are also
>      needed with SP2013 on-premises. These are located in the
>      Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll assembly, which is by
>      default installed to C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management
>      Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell folder. Latest version
>      is from May 2014, but the previous released version from 2012 does
>      also work. since we have not introduced any real changes on the
>      client side of the code.
> 4. Enable [AdministrationSiteType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.administrationsitetype%28v=office.15%29.aspx) from one site collection in
>      your on-premises farm which will be acting like a admin site for
>      site collection creation. This could be for example root site in the
>      root site collection of the application where you create the new
>      site collections.

Please follow [Provisioning site collections using SP App model in on-premises with just CSOM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom.aspx) post for a more details.